# How do I find the area of an unusual shape?

Tags: geometry

[image]

I'm suck on 6 (a).

I know the area will be expressed in terms of $\pi$ because the shaded region is curved.

I sliced the square into two right triangles and found the hypotheses which $a\sqrt{2}$.

Afterwards, I'm stuck. How do I find the shaded region and what are hints for the other parts of 6, (b) and (c)?

Comment: You do usual integration with the use of usual parametrization.

Comment: @Kaster we can't use calculus on this book problem. This book assumes mathematical knowledge below calculus. I'm curious to know how to solve this problem using elementary algebra or geometry.

Answer (score 1):

The drawings are lousy and they assume we will make a lot of assumptions but, if we assume the curved lines are *circular* arcs.  (It's not enough to say "curved" "means" pi).  Then the top right corner to the lower arc is 1/4 of a circle with radius 1.  The lower left corner is another 1/4 of a circle.  If we add those two 1/4 circles together we'd get an entire square plus the shaded area counted twice.  So the shaded region is two quarter circles - the square.

So $Area = 2(1/4*\pi*a^2) - a^2 = a^2(\frac {\pi}{2} - 1)$

b) you have two half circles with radius a.  You add them and that wedge section is counted twice.  So the *unshaded* region will be 2 half circles minus the wedge.  The wedge section is the same wedge in a.  The shaded region is the area of the square minus the unshaded region.

c)  The shaded area is the area of an equilateral triangle minus 3 sections of a circle.

Comment: Note that in c), the three sections of the circle probably refer to half circle.

Comment: @OFRBG in c) the angles are 60 degrees.  3 of them make 180 degrees.  That's one half of a circle.  So the *unshaded* area is 1/2 \* pi * a^2.  The area of the equilateral triangle is another issue.

Answer (score 1):

Cut out the shape and weigh it.

Similarly,
to estimate the volume
of an unusual shape,
place it is a sandbox
and get the weight of
the removed sand.

This is probably not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Cut out two paper quadrants of circle radius $a$ and cover the area in the square as given. Notice that it is the overlap area you are interested in evaluating:

$$ A = \frac{\pi}{4} a^2 + \frac{\pi}{4} a^2 - a^2. $$